# Updating the url of a navigation node in moss programatically

Tags: sharepoint, navigation

Can anyone see why this should not work:

```
SPSite topNavigationSite = new SPSite("http://moss");
SPWeb topNavigationWeb = topNavigationSite.OpenWeb();
SPNavigationNodeCollection topNavigationBarNodes = topNavigationWeb.Navigation.TopNavigationBar;
SPNavigationNode updateNode = topNavigationBarNodes.Navigation.GetNodeByUrl("/about");
updateNode.Url = "";
topNavigationWeb.Update();
```

I can see debugging that the url get's set to "" but when the page renders, the navigation still shows the url as /about/default.aspx

I'm running this in page_load and expected it to update the moss database with the new url value.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is 3years old! but as there is no where online about updating a current url!

I had to do some debugging and this is what iv come up with! By the way I got the hint from

```
topNavigationWeb.Update();
```

indicating that its updating a list! hint hint!

a bit of background! I wanted to update the quick links from a list when they add, update and delete an item from the list! On my list I have two columns Title and URL!

I then created a project in VS 2010, its an event receiver that is connected only to that list (done in the elements.xml file)

within the .cs file I added item added, item deleting(not deleted ;) ) and item updated

public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)

public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)

public override void ItemDeleting(SPItemEventProperties properties)

now within each method you can simply call this method!

**add/update**

```
   public static void AddQuickLaunchItem(string header, string url, SPWeb web)
   {
       SPNavigationNodeCollection quickLaunch = web.Navigation.QuickLaunch;

       // try to get quick launch header
       SPNavigationNode nodeHeader =
       quickLaunch.Cast<SPNavigationNode>().Where(n => n.Title == header).FirstOrDefault();

       //if header not found create it
       if (nodeHeader == null)
       {
           nodeHeader = quickLaunch.AddAsFirst(new SPNavigationNode(header, url,true));
       }
       else
       {

           web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;


           nodeHeader = quickLaunch.Cast<SPNavigationNode>().Where(n => n.Title == header).First() ;
           nodeHeader.Url = url;

           web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
       }
       nodeHeader.Update();
       web.Update();
   }
```

the first part is checking if the node exists using the title (header)! I'm comparing between what headers there are and from the list item:

```
SPNavigationNode nodeHeader =
           quickLaunch.Cast<SPNavigationNode>().Where(n => n.Title == header).FirstOrDefault();
```

this part is the comparison:

```
n.Title == header
```

I'm getting these values (header and url / spweb) like so:

public static void AddQuickLaunchItem(string header, string url, SPWeb web)

the method that is calling the above would look like this:

```
   private void addloopweblinks(SPSite siteCollection, SPItemEventProperties properties)
   {
       // Enumerate through each site and apply branding.
       foreach (SPWeb web in siteCollection.AllWebs)
       {
           AddQuickLaunchItem(properties.ListItem["Title"].ToString(), properties.ListItem["URL"].ToString(), web);
       }
   }
```

and the above method is called within the itemadded and itemupdated ;) passing the values like so:

```
   public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
   {
           using (SPSite siteCollection = new SPSite(properties.WebUrl))
           {
               if (siteCollection != null)
               {
                       addloopweblinks(siteCollection, properties);
               }
           }
   }
```

similar things can be done for the delete ;)

SPNavigationNode nodeHeader =
           quickLaunch.Cast().Where(n => n.Title == header).FirstOrDefault();

that will get the node!

nodeHeader.delete();
nodeHeader.update();

that will delete the item!

so in your case what you need, I don't know if you noticed it was this part:

```
    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

    nodeHeader = quickLaunch.Cast<SPNavigationNode>().Where(n => n.Title == header).First() ;
    nodeHeader.Url = url;

    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;

    nodeHeader.Update();
    web.Update();
```

as you can see what i mean by the hint! nodeHeader.Update(); didnt update the url, when debugging it does change but when i go to the update part it doesnt work :( and it clicked in i need `web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;` loool only becuse I experienced a similar situation before!

for you it would be:

```
using(SPSite topNavigationSite = new SPSite("http://moss"))
{
  using(SPWeb topNavigationWeb = topNavigationSite.OpenWeb())
  {
     web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
     SPNavigationNodeCollection topNavigationBarNodes =topNavigationWeb.Navigation.TopNavigationBar;
     SPNavigationNode updateNode = topNavigationBarNodes.Navigation.GetNodeByUrl("/about");
     updateNode.Url = "";
     updateNode.Update();
     web.Update();
     web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
  }
}
```

If the user doesnt have the sufficent rights than you need to encapsulate the above with runwithelevatedprivalages :) hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
updateNode.Update();
topNavigationWeb.Update();
```

It doesn't look like you are updating the SPNavigationNode object. (Note: you may not need the second Update call.)

Comment: Alex, can I loop and see all the spnavigationnodes as I think now it may be set to "" and therefore I can't use GetNodeByUrl :)

Comment: @orl78: Yes, you should be able to do a `foreach` over the SPNavigationNodeCollection and examine the nodes.